# How to tell if content URI is from an SD card?

Tags: android

In my app I let the user choose a directory using the Storage Access Framework (for Android 5.0 and newer).
It looks like content URIs of files (or folders) from internal storage begin with
**content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary** and those of files from an SD card begin with **content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/xxxx-xxxx**. Is this true for all Android version (≥ 5.0) and for all brands/manufacturers?

Comment: I would not make any assumptions about the structure of any `Uri` returned by the Storage Access Framework. After all, there are other options besides the ones you have listed (Google Drive, SMB shares, etc.).

Comment: When I open a file from Seafile, it begins with **content://com.seafile.seadroid2/tree/**. So I guess that all the options you are talking about don't even begin with **content://com.android.externalstorage**. Maybe someone can disprove my assumption with an example!?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to eliminate the assumption?

Comment: Do you know a better solution? Until now the users sees the current directory as **primary:DCIM** or **0123-4567:DCIM**. That's not very user friendly. I would like to replace it by **Internal storage: DCIM** or **SD card: DCIM**, for example. Up to Android 4.4, the users sees the real path (because I'm using a classical directory picker).

Comment: "Do you know a better solution?" -- don't worry about it. The user chooses what the user chooses. "Until now the users sees the current directory as primary:DCIM or 0123-4567:DCIM" -- I don't know what you are using to generate those. Use whatever `DocumentFile` returns for `getName()` and be done with the matter. It is up to the storage provider to determine what the display name is. In principle, it should match whatever the user saw in the Storage Access Framework UI when choosing that content.

Comment: "I don't know what you are using to generate those." I'm extracting them from the URI. It's just a little orientation for the user because when you open a folder with the SAF, you see a folder name (probably the last one opened, like "DCIM") and you could mistake it for another folder also named "DCIM" (for example that one on a SD card). But you're right, it's not really necessary. Just nice to have.

Comment: "I'm extracting them from the URI" -- use the display names from `DocumentFile`. If desired, work your way up the parent chain and get *their* display names, to assemble "breadcrumbs" showing the hierarchy.